# Cast the elements while inserting into a map in java

Tags: java, java-8

I've two maps with below definitions,

**map1:**

```
Map<String, List<Object>> devicePojoMap = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();
```

**map2:**

```
Map<String, List<String>> devicePojoMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Now, we need to put all the elements from map1 to map2 with respective key value pair. To do the same, I'm iterating and doing the casting something like below and then puting in to the map2.

```
physicalInterfaceList = (List<String>) devicePojoMap.get("physicalInterfaceList");
```

Is there a way to avoid iteration and insert the map1 to directly to map2. please suggest on the same

Comment: There's no type-safe way that the compiler would allow other than iterating (imperatively or declaratively) through `devicePojoMap` and casting values.

Answer (score 1):

Your question boils down to:

Can I treat a `List<Object>` as a `List<String>`?

### TL;DR:

Yes, you can, but you undermine compile-time type safety if you do so. So, **decide wisely if it's worth the risk**.

Now that **you have been warned**, let's discuss how it's possible.

At runtime, all generics info has been erased, so both `List<Object>` and `List<String>` are just instances implementing the `List` interface. So, casting from `List<Object>` to `List<String>` will not give you a `ClassCastException` at that place, as at runtime it effectively is a no-op (you might later get ClassCastExceptions or strange behaviour related to the list elements, see below..).

So, the difference exists at compile time only. With `List<Object>`, the compiler will allow inserting elements of any type, whereas with `List<String>` the compiler will only allow inserting `String` and mark as error any attempt where other types might be involved. So, it's only the compiler responsible for the important assumption that a `List<String>` only contains strings.

If you are **really, really, really** sure (e.g. ready to bet a few thousand dollars on it) that the `List<Object>` will only contain `String` instances, you can just cast from `List<Object>` to `List<String>`. But if this assumption later turns out to be wrong, you might get strange behaviour, e.g. a stray ClassCastException in rather unrelated code. That will probably become a nightmare to debug.

By the way, if you are really sure about the lists only containing strings, why then does the original declaration use `List<Object>` and not `List<String>`?

The compiler will not allow the cast immediately (e.g. your code line with the cast to `List<String>` gives a compiler error). To make it work you can write a raw-type cast, something like

```
List<Object> objectList = ...;
List<String> stringList = (List) objectList;
```

and of course, you'll get the appropriate warnings from the compiler for that unsafe piece of code.

In your case, the lists are embedded in maps, so the piece of code might look like

```
Map<String, List<Object>> map1 = ...;
Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>((Map) map1);
```

or even

```
Map<String, List<Object>> map1 = ...;
Map<String, List<String>> map2 = (Map) map1;
```

To sum it up: With some tricky casting (and a crucial assumption on list contents), you can avoid the iteration, but **there are serious risks if doing so**.